# Sending multiple parameter from one page to another

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using below code to pass two parameter from one page to another,

```
link.NavigateUrl = "~/OutageInfo.aspx?outageID=" + outageid + "toolid="+toolid;
```

code on other page

```
var  x = this.Request.QueryString["outageID"];
int y = Convert.ToInt32(this.Request.QueryString["toolid"]);
```

the output I am getting is x="10toolid=1" and y=0
but it should be x=10 and y=1, what mistake i am making

Answer (score 2):

**It should be**

```
ink.NavigateUrl = "~/OutageInfo.aspx?outageID=" + outageid + "&toolid="+toolid;
```

**instead of**

```
ink.NavigateUrl = "~/OutageInfo.aspx?outageID=" + outageid + "toolid="+toolid;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try editting this line..

```
link.NavigateUrl = "~/OutageInfo.aspx?outageID=" + outageid+ "&"+ "toolid="+toolid;
```

You must append the second query string with **&** sign..In your case it is considering as a single query string..

Answer (score 2):

You should put like this

```
       link.NavigateUrl = "~/OutageInfo.aspx?outageID=" + outageid + "&toolid="+toolid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Seperate parameters using &:

link.NavigateUrl = "~/OutageInfo.aspx?outageID=" + outageid &toolid="+toolid;

Answer (score 0):

Here **&** parameter separates parameters in url you didnt mention **&** in your url so it cant able to split and pass to corresponding QueryString.So use below Format then you will get your required result.

```
link.NavigateUrl = "~/OutageInfo.aspx?outageID=" + outageid + "&toolid="+toolid;
```

Then it appears like

localhost:...\OutageInfo.aspx?outageID=12231&toolid=12321

Then in aspx.cs file you will get these values

```
var  x = this.Request.QueryString["outageID"];//var x=12231
int y = Convert.ToInt32(this.Request.QueryString["toolid"]);//int y=12321
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send multiple parameter from page one to page two using querystring but you have to use '&' as a field separator
see below snippet

```
link.NavigateUrl = "~/OutageInfo.aspx?outageID=" + outageid + "&toolid="+tooled;.
```

In above sample  'outage' and 'toolid' has '&' as separator